# Keras fitting ignoring nan values

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, keras

I am training a neural network to do regression, (1 input and 1 output). Let's `x` and `y` be the usual input and output dataset, respectively.

My problem is that the `y` dataset (not the `x`) have some values set to nan, so the fitting goes to nan. I wonder if there is an option to ignore the nan values in the fitting, in a similar way to the numpy functions `np.nanmean` to calculate the mean ignoring nans and so on.

If that option does not exist I suppose I would have to find the nan values and erase them manually, **and at the same time** erase the values in `x` corresponding to the nan position in `y`.

```
x       y
2       4
3       2
4      np.nan
5       7
6      np.nan
7      np.nan
```

In this simple example the nan values in the y column should be removed and at the same time the corresponding values in the x column (4, 6, 7).

Thank you.

**EDIT:** Ok, I have a problem filtering the nans, I do:

```
for index, x in np.ndenumerate(a):
    if x == np.nan:
        print index, x
```

and it doesn't print anything and I am sure there are nan values...

**EDIT (SELF ANSWER):** Ok, I have found a way to localize the nans:

```
for index, x in np.ndenumerate(a):
      if x != x:
           print index, x
```

Comment: Is the NAN really relevant? Otherwise just remove them from your training data or map them to a specific constant (like 0 or -1). Way easier but same result as your proposition.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking that, but the values should be removed in both columns, so you have to find the position of the nans in the array and then erase them. Then you would have to find the corresponding position in the x column and erase them.

Comment: I don't see the problem? If you find a NAN on the n'th row of y, you also delete it on the n'th row of x.

Comment: Original question edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments, simply remove the nan as a preprocessing step:

```
import numpy as np

x = range(2,8)
y = [4,2,np.nan,7,np.nan,np.nan]

for a,b in zip(x,y):
    if str(b) == 'nan':
        x.remove(a)
        y.remove(b)

print x,y
```

produces `[2, 3, 5] [4, 2, 7]`.

If you're using some tool to preprocess the data which gives you the `np.nan`, check whether the API allows you to disable this behavior and take a minute to think whether this is **really** the behavior you want (or if you e.g. want to map this to constants because you find your input to be valuable even though they have no labels).

Comment: Not so simple in my case, where the data is a timeseries, tagged per-frame. What would I do in that case?

Comment: @Gulzar You can also go for imputation instead of removing these values. However, correctly handling "missing data" without destroying underlying statistical relationships  is a pretty big topic in and of itself because it is different for each use case and requires a proper analysis of why values are missing. I'd suggest some basic research into this to see what you could do in your specific use case.