# Keras - is it possible to train classification models with missing data?

Tags: python, neural-network, dataset, keras

I've been scrolling through forums for the past few hours but can't seem to find an answer.

If I have a dataset that is something along the lines of the small example shown below. Where A, B, C, D and E are input values, and X and Y are output values.

(the missing data being valued 'null' is irrelevant, could be anything)

```
A     B     C     D     E     X      Y
7     6     3     3     2     11     4
5     6     0     0     7     15     7
3     3     9     null  7     12     7
7     null  7     null  7     12     13
null  7     4     6     12    13     4
null  5     7     6     null  14     7
2     6     0     0     2     13     3
7     null  7     null  2     13     7
```

Is there a way to train a neural network within keras such that it skips over the null values, but still takes into account that row of data?

E.g. in the third row it would skip over the value for D as it is null, but would still fit using the other 4 columns, and the 2 output columns?

For the task i'm attempting, the rows with null values cannot be ignored. They also cannot be replaced with any other value (e.g. can't predict a replacement value).

Comment: When you are not sure as you say "can't predict a replacement value", better go with replacing them with column average.                              
 Check if this link helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37747886/keras-fitting-ignoring-nan-values

Comment: Can't do that either. Its a dataset of outfits, its validity would be ruined if I found a mean due to the subjective nature.

Answer (score 0):

Hypothetical solution on top of my mind would be first train the neural network with the non null rows and then save the neural network parameters. In the next steps update the saved neural network by training on non null rows iterating each column to find the non null rows. Suppose in the next steps you would train the model with A, B, C, E columns as D has null value. If you implement a recursive function it will do the whole job for us.